# Block specific cookies?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, chrome-for-android

Some sites use cookies to annoy users in various ways (i.e. by nagging return visitors). Is there a way to block specific sites from using cookies in Chrome without disabling cookies globally? I know this is possible on the desktop, but I cannot figure out how to do it on Android.

Comment: Have you tried [this](http://www.androidpolice.com/2015/01/29/nom-nom-no-chrome-beta-now-lets-disable-third-party-cookies-still-allowing-first-party-ones/) (for Chrome Beta, says to go to Settings to control cookie behavior per site), or this [answer](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2392971?hl=en) by Google?

Comment: Yes, that allows disabling cookies globally, but not per site. I want to block e.g. *.example.com from setting cookies. I saw the answer, but something must have changed in Lollipop, because I cannot access the settings that way.